# difficulty referencing functions, using prototype

Tags: javascript

I am working on HTML 5 Canvas game, with a gameloop.

Here is my code so far.  It doesn't do anything and that is fine, but I am getting an error

TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'Update' [http://localhost:2516/scripts/lib/Game.js:47]

Edit:  This code works, it no longer reflects the problem, it reflects the solution

```
  var game;
    var Game = function () {
    }


   Game.prototype.Update = function () {

}

Game.prototype.Draw = function () {

}

function GameLoop () {


    game.Update(); //this is line 47
    //context.save();
    game.Draw();
   // context.restore();
    setTimeout(GameLoop, 10);
}
function Start() {
    game = new Game();
   GameLoop();
}
```

Edit: I think the "this" is looking at the document instead of the Game object, which I don't understand why or how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely with this line within `GameLoop`:

```
setTimeout(this.GameLoop, 10);
```

You can't pass a "method" reference; only function references. So, when this is called by `setTimeout`, it will be called without a set context, like you'd called it as:

```
GameLoop();
```

You have to either [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it:

```
setTimeout(this.GameLoop.bind(this), 10);
```

Or wrap it in another function similar to what `bind` will do (saving `this` as `self` as the function will have its own value for `this`):

```
var self = this;
// ...
setTimeout(function () {
    self.GameLoop();
}, 10);
```

Comment: It's not exactly true to say you can't pass method references to `setTimeout` - you can, it's just the `this` context will be lost. For methods that don't depend on context it's no problem.

Comment: I think this is the answer.  I removed the gameloop function from Game.prototype.  Assigned than called game.Update and game.Draw, instead of this.Update  it seems to work.  Not throwing any errors anyway.

Comment: @Utkanos Perhaps not the best way to explain it, but this was the point I was trying to make -- "*it's just the `this` context will be lost.*" It's no longer considered a "method" without a set context, which it won't have being passed like that.